# Emphatic statement and questions

Tags: grammar, questions, emphasis

We can use helping verbs like do, does, and did before verbs for emphasis, as in:

> He knows the truth.
> He **does** know the truth. (More emphatic)

But does the same rule apply to information questions? As in

> Who knows the truth?
> Who **does** know the truth?

Comment: Why wouldn't it apply to that?

Comment: @Lambie well, my friend insists that we never use helping verbs after 'who' unless it's the objective form, like 'Who does he ask for address?' and the subjective form is only 'Who asks for the address?' But not 'Who does ask for the address?' I know they have totally different structure with different meanings though.

Comment: @Lambie so Who does know the truth is idiomatic, right?

Comment: Ok, first, your friend is mistaken. 1) "Who does he ask for addresses or an address [when he needs them]? Now. imagine some office procedure. 2) One person could say: Who does ask for the address [when clients call]? ask for an address or addresses and ask someone for an address or addresses.

Comment: "Who knows [a fact]? You don't? Or you? Well who **does** know?"

Comment: The point about this supportive "do" is that it places stress on the positive or negative polarity of the clause.  In your example, there is an emphatic positive. The unemphatic version is "Who knows the truth?"

Comment: Places stress or just stresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps "emphasis" isn't the most helpful word for OP to use here. The example statement...

> 1: *He **does** know the truth*

...would be unlikely (but not impossible) if it was simply intended to convey the "emphasis" of, for example,...

> 2: *He **really** knows the truth!* <sub>(there's absolutely no doubt about that!)</sub>

Normally, the "do-support" of #1 above ***refutes / contradicts*** some earlier assertion, such as...

> 3a: *"I doubt if even John knows the truth of the matter."*
> 3b: *"You're mistaken. He **does** know the truth."*

Note that the word ***does*** will *always* carry heavy stress in such contexts.

---

By the same token, in OP's *question* context, including do-support, as...

> 4: *Who **does** know the truth?*

...would normally only occur in contexts where the speaker has just been told that someone he thought *might* know the truth actually *doesn't* - equivalent to...

> 5: *If what I previously thought **isn't** true, then what **is** true?*

OR

> 6a: *"It's no use asking me. I don't have a clue!"*
> 6b: *"Who **does** know the truth, then?"*

Comment: John: Mary doesn't know the truth. Sam: But she does know the truth. And that kind of construction is very used.

Comment: Surely that's just another an example of the specific sub-type of "emphasis" I'm calling ***refutation***, illustrated by my examples #3a/#3b above.

Comment: I think your first statement is misleading for an ELL OP.

Comment: @Lambie: Wot? You think the difference between ***emphasis*** and ***refutation / contradiction*** is too complicated for someone learning English? Personally, I think the first sentence of my answer here is as good as anything I've ever written on ELL! :)

Comment: Let's not confuse **grammar** (emphatic use of an auxiliary) with what context it is used in. emphasis and refutation don't have the same status.

Comment: I'm not getting confused. I'm simply pointing out that *whatever* the OP understands by the word ***emphasis***, it's clearly not helping him to understand the syntactic affordances and semantics of auxilliary do-support in assertions and questions. And *in my opinion*, the OP will gain a better understanding of the difference between "emphatic" *"It **does** annoy me when you do that!"* and "refutative" *"You're mistaken. He **does** know the truth"* as per my example #3.

Comment: One term is used to teach (by tradition) the thing itself. The other is what the thing does. And you can go on and on about it.  Calling this by the formal linguistic name of do-support does not change this fact at all. And I never said  "you" were confused. Let's be clear about that, at least.